# Time out or get a result when available

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a system that can put and get messages from a messaging middleware (JMS), which is asynchronous. I need to provide an API that allows synchronous call, as in, when the API/method is called, it returns only when a response message is received or until a specified time out. In short, the calling thread needs to wait until woken up when the response message is received or until the time out.

[`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) from Java 8 does the job, but this library needs to work in Java 7 and I couldn't find any equivalent in Java 7. Guava has [`ListenableFuture`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html), but it doesn't fit my requirement as I need the thread that called to be held while waiting for the response.

Here is a class that can hold the calling thread and return when a response is delivered by another thread. I am looking to avoid any code smells or concurrency issues. Any additional tests and constructive comments are welcome!

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

/**
 * Object to hold the calling thread while we wait for a response message from client
 *
 */
public class SyncResult<T> {

    private T result;

    private final ReentrantLock messageLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition messageCondition = messageLock.newCondition();
    // In the very remote off chance that result is already available and 
    // wait is not required
    private final AtomicBoolean messageReceived = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    /**
     * Sets the given result and notifies the calling thread to return the result
     */
    public void setResult(T result) {
        messageLock.lock();
        this.result = result;
        messageReceived.set(true);
        messageCondition.signal();
        messageLock.unlock();
    }

    /**
     * Return the result or time out and get an exception
     */ 
    public T getResult(long timeOut, TimeUnit timeUnit) throws InterruptedException,
        TimeoutException {
        boolean receivedSignal = false;
        messageLock.lock();
        if(!messageReceived.get()) {
            receivedSignal = messageCondition.await(timeOut, timeUnit);
        } 
        messageLock.unlock();
        // If messageReceived is true, then we return null
        if(!receivedSignal && !messageReceived.get()) {
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Unit tests:**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class SyncResultTests {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SyncResultTests.class);

    @Test
    public void testTimelyDelivery() throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        final SyncResult<String> syncResult = new SyncResult<>();
        final String myResult = "Done";

        Runnable messageWorker = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                syncResult.setResult(myResult);
            }
        };

        ExecutorService executors = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executors.submit(messageWorker);

        String result = syncResult.getResult(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Assert.assertEquals(myResult, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEarlyDelivery() throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        final SyncResult<String> syncResult = new SyncResult<>();
        final String myResult = "Done";

        Runnable messageWorker = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                syncResult.setResult(myResult);
            }
        };

        ExecutorService executors = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executors.submit(messageWorker);
        executors.shutdown();
        Assert.assertTrue(executors.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS), "Message result setter thread not terminated");

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String result = syncResult.getResult(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        Assert.assertEquals(myResult, result);
        Assert.assertTrue(elapsedTime < 2000L);

    }

    @Test
    public void testLateDelivery() throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        final SyncResult<String> syncResult = new SyncResult<>();
        final String myResult = "Done";

        Runnable messageWorker = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                syncResult.setResult(myResult);
            }
        };

        try {
            syncResult.getResult(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Assert.fail("Result should not be returned");
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        // We should still be able to deliver a result
        ExecutorService executors = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executors.submit(messageWorker);
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions = TimeoutException.class)
    public void testNoDelivery() throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        final SyncResult<String> syncResult = new SyncResult<>();
        syncResult.getResult(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Assert.fail("Result should not be returned");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for testing `result == null`?

Comment: Good point. My first draft did not have the `messageReceived` field, so I relied on `result == null`. I just updated it to use a better condition, the boolean value from `Condition.await()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are my suggestions and the full code afterward:

1. Always unlock in a `finally` clause. This is specially true in the `getResult` method, if the `await` call is interrupted, the lock will never be released.
2. Use `signalAll` instead of `signal`, if several threads are waiting for the result, with `signal` only one will stop waiting.
3. When declaring a variable, use the most generic type. In your code, you should declare `messageLock` as a `Lock` instead of a `ReentrantLock`.
4. the `messageReceived` variable is always used in a lock/unlock block and then could be a simple `boolean` instead of an `AtomicBoolean`

Below is the code with these suggestions :

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

/**
 * Object to hold the calling thread while we wait for a response message from client
 *
 */
public class SyncResult<T> {

    private T result;

    private final Lock messageLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition messageCondition = messageLock.newCondition();
    // In the very remote off chance that result is already available and 
    // wait is not required
    private boolean messageReceived = false;

    /**
     * Sets the given result and notifies the calling thread to return the result
     */
    public void setResult(T result) {
        messageLock.lock();
        try {
            this.result = result;
            messageReceived = true;
            messageCondition.signalAll();
        } finally {
            messageLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the result or time out and get an exception
     */ 
    public T getResult(long timeOut, TimeUnit timeUnit) throws InterruptedException,
        TimeoutException {
        boolean receivedSignal = false;
        messageLock.lock();
        try {
            if(!messageReceived) {
                receivedSignal = messageCondition.await(timeOut, timeUnit);
            } 
            // If messageReceived is true, then we return null
            if(!receivedSignal && !messageReceived) {
                throw new TimeoutException();
            }
            return result;
        }
        finally {
            messageLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: #2 is a great point I missed as I was intending for only one thread to call this object, but it can easily be called by multiple threads. Excellent catch on #4 as well, as the variables in the lock block will be synchronized among threads. However, the `messageReceived` field cannot be final in the code above.

Comment: #4 yep you are right, I modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, this is a well formed answer!